How do I get sqlalchemy subqueries to retain their ORM type?
I have a query with subquery. It partitions based on ID and selects the newest of each one in the partitions. It works fine:
subquery = db.query(
    func.rank()
    .over(
        order_by=Table.CreatedAt.desc(),
        partition_by=[Table.ID],
    )
    .label("rank"),
    Table,
).subquery()
rows: list[Table] = db.query(subquery).filter(subquery.c.rank == 1).all()

The problems is the type of rows isn't list[Table] but rather list[Rows] and it loses all of the ORM information.
How do I get it to return list[Table]?

The solution is to query for the model class, passing the subquery to the query's from_statement method:
stmt = db.query(subquery).filter(subquery.c.rank == 1)
rows: List[Table] = db.query(Table).from_statement(stmt).all()

or using from_statement in SQLAlchemy 2.0's style:
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
stmt = sa.select(subquery).where(subquery.c.rank == 1)    
rows: List[Table] = s.scalars(sa.select(Table).from_statement(stmt)).all() 

